# Type(3,) returns an integer instead of a tuple in python, why?

Tags: python, types, tuples

`type(3,)` returns the int type, while

```
t = 3,
type(t)
```

returns the tuple type.
Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside the parentheses that form the function call operator, the comma is *not* for building tuples, but for separating arguments.  Thus, `type(3, )` is equivalent to `type(3)`.  An additional comma at the end of the argument list is allowed by the grammar.  You need an extra pair of parens to build a tuple:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     print x
... 
>>> f(3)
3
>>> f(3,)
3
>>> f((3,))
(3,)
```

Answer (score 6):

The builtin `type()` is a function, so the comma is being parsed as an argument separator rather than a tuple constructor.

```
>>> type(3,)
<type 'int'>

>>> type((3,))
<type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Regardless of how many arguments `f` takes, the comma will be parsed as an argument separator.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect Python ignores a trailing comma in function arguments:

```
def f (a):
    print a
    print type(a)

>>> f(3,)
3
<type 'int'>
```

Using comma-separated values without parentheses to create a tuple is a trick that doesn't work everywhere. List comprehensions is a good example:

```
>>> [a,a*2 for a in range(4)]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [a,a*2 for a in range(4)]
             ^
```

You have to do this:

```
>>> [(a,a*2) for a in range(4)]
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6)]
```

List unpacking works fine, though, so it's a bit variable where unbounded, comma-separated values are allowed:

```
>>> [(a,b) for a, b in zip(range(4),range(4))]
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In `func(bunch_of_args)` you are allowed to follow the last arg with a comma, just like in

```
alist = [1, 2, 3, ]
```